# How to get button if an item is selected in Jquery Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) in a HTML table and works fine, but i want to get a button when an item is selected.

I tried with this:

```
    $(function () {
        tableToGrid(".mytable", {
            autowidth:true,
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 20,
            viewrecords: true,
            loadui: true,
            rowList: [10,20,50],
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Multi Select Example",

            onSelectAll : function(aSel,selected) {
                if(selected){
                    var value =0;
                    for(var i=0;i<aSel.length;i++){
                        var data = jQuery(".mytable").getRowData(aSel[i]);
                        value += parseFloat(data.total);
                    }
                    jQuery('#gbox_').before( $('<button class="button" type="button" value="Edit">Edit</button>') );
                } else {
                    jQuery(".button").remove();
                }
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                if (selRows.length === 0) {
                    $(".button").remove();
                } else {
                    $('#gbox_').before( $('<button class="button" type="button" value="Edit">Edit</button>') );
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

When I click on an item i get the button, but for every selected item:

[image: for each selected element i get the button]

And when I select all I get no button. Why?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: which button you want to get? It's difficult understand what you do from the code which you posted. It's unclear how many elements on the page have class `mytable` or which has class `button`, where you defined element with `id="gbox_"`, why you insert **on every** select of row new button before `#gbox_`, ... I can continue.... **Could you describe what the code should do and what you current code didn't do now?** You should post HTML fragment which is important to understand your code.

Comment: What the code sholud do:
**i want to get a button when an item is selected**. What my corrent code do: **When I click on an item i get the button, but for every selected item**.
You can see the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mXHje/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to listen to the [`onSelectAll`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event for that.

Comment: Thank you so much David! I added the code `onSelectAll` and works fine, but on `onSelectRow` when I click on a row i get the button for every selected row. (as shown in the picture, you can see the button "Edit" repeated three times)

Comment: @Fuiba: Do you always want just one row? Currently, you're removing the active buttons if there's exactly 0 selected rows, but why don't you always do that? `$(".button").remove(); if(selRows.length > 0) { $('#gbox_').before( $('<button class="button" type="button" value="Edit">Edit</button>') ); }`

Comment: I added an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mXHje/ try to select rows and you'll see the buttons for each row selected. I want that when i select multiple rows to get only ONE BUTTON.

Comment: @Fuiba: In that case, what I suggested in my previous comment would work for you. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JY5Hk/). A neater approach, however, might be to create a hidden button, and just toggle it depending on whether there are any checked rows. No matter how many times you show an already visible button, after all, it'll still just be one.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question. To add the button to the clicked item, you have to use this code  :

```
$(function (e) {
            tableToGrid(".mytable", {
                autowidth:true,
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 20,
                viewrecords: true,
                loadui: true,
                rowList: [10,20,50],
                multiselect: true,
                caption: "Multi Select Example",
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                    if (selRows.length === 0) {
                        $(".button").remove();
                    } else {
                      $(e.target).before( $('<button class="button" type="button" value="Edit">Edit</button>') );
                    }

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: or adding parent() by use : $(e.target).parent().before( $('<button class="button" type="button" value="Edit">Edit</button>') );